# How to call a method from asp.net .cs page from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call the method insert which is in Edit.aspx.cs but it is not calling

```
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

   <script language="javascript">
               function insert() {

              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "Edituser.aspx.cs/insert",
               success: function () { alert('success'); },
               error: function () { alert('error'); }

                });


              }


</script>

 <input type="button" id="Button1" style="display: none" onclick="changecourse(); insert();"  value="add" />
```

**My codebehind**

```
    public void insert()
    {
        string a = Hidden1.Value;
        string UserId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginId"]);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserDepot (UserId,DepotId)" +
            "VALUES ('" + UserId + "','" + a + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You certainly can't issue a request to a `.cs` file like that... cfr Milind's answer here under.

Answer (score 4):

For it to work, ensure that the method location set in `url` is correct and that the method is `public` and `static` and that is has a `[WebMethod]` attribute added such as:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void doAll()
{
    //do something
}
```

if the `url` is "/Default.aspx/insert" then your method should look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void insert()
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put WebMethods in a code behind page - interesting, do you consider it good practice or would you use a separate WS/WCF?

Comment: WebMethod indicates "the method exposed as part of the XML Web service." and it enables the method to be called through the web service. So i believe you should be using this

Comment: I'd use ASP.NET Web API if you are considering WCF. It's THAT much easier... But if you only have a few methods it would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Send a QueryString to edit user to aspx

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Edituser.aspx?run=add",
           success: function () { alert('success'); },
           error: function () { alert('error'); }

            });
```

then put a if to pageload of Edituser.aspx

```
if (Request.QueryString["run"] == "add")
            {
               insert();//your Function Name
            }
```